# '2–0 down', what does it mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What purpose does 'down' serve in this sentence, what does it mean?

> At 2–0 **down** with ten minutes left, you have to go for broke.

Comment: When a football team are 2–0 _down_ they are currently losing the game. (We _write_ it as **2–0** but would _say_, "They are losing two-nil" or "they're two-nil down".) 2–0 _up_ ("Two nil _up_") would mean the team were winning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the "down", it's impossible to tell whether the side in question -- in this case, "you" -- has the 2 points or the 0 points. Saying "2-0 down" makes it clear that they have the 0 points, and is equivalent to saying that they are "losing 2-0".

Conversely, you could say "2-0 up" to mean the same as "winning 2-0", but I suspect that's less common than the "down" case. (Hmm, although maybe that's simply because all the teams I support are crap and always losing! :-) )